# PHP: Workaround to reuse modified private parent method

Tags: php, oop

I like to modify one private method of an inherited class.

These are my requirements:

- I can't modify the parent class.
- I have to reuse the code of the inherited class.
- I need to append some code before the parent's private method code.

Basically I like this code

```
<?php

class ParentClass
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        echo 'Doing parent stuff';

        $this->doPrivateStuff();

        echo 'Doing more parent stuff';
    }

    private function doPrivateStuff()
    {
        echo 'Doing private stuff';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    private function doPrivateStuff()
    {
        echo 'Additional code';

        parent::doPrivateStuff();
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass;
$obj->doStuff();

?>
```

to output

```
Doing parent stuff
Additional code
Doing private stuff
Doing more parent stuff
```

instead of

```
Doing parent stuff
Doing private stuff
Doing more parent stuff
```

I know that my code "fails" because `doPrivateStuff` is a private method.

**What's the best workaround to reuse a modified version of the private method anyway?**

PS:

My current workaround is to implement the methods `doStuff` and `doPrivateStuff` in my `ChildClass` by parsing the parent's methods' bodies via reflection and `eval`uating them.

I don't exactly consider this a "clean" approach, ahem. So I'm happy to read your recommendations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @Phil! It showed that my example was not clear enough. Your suggested approach won't work, because `parent::doStuff` does more than just outputting one line. Please see my fixed example!

Answer (score 0):

Do this :

```
<?php

class ParentClass
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        // Some code

        $this->doPrivateStuff();

        // More code
    }

    private function doPrivateStuff()
    {
        echo 'Doing private stuff';
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function doStuff()
    {
        echo 'Additional code';

        parent::doStuff();
    }
}

$obj = new ChildClass;
$obj->doStuff();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sébastien! Sadly, that won't work. My example was unclear, sorry. Please see my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257243/php-workaround-to-reuse-modified-private-parent-method#comment111858943_63257243) and fixed example.

Comment: It's impossible to achieve what you want. That a principle of OOP with private function. The only way is to add a new function in ParentClass to be overriden in the ChildClass

Comment: I wouldn't say that it's impossible. True, you can't achieve my desired code reuse via PHP-style inheritance, but there are workarounds. I presented one at the end of my question. I wonder if there is a less "hacky" solution.